# What is the energy density of voltaic piles?

Tags: batteries, energy, electrostatic

I heard voltaic piles have very small power but long lifetimes so I was wondering what their energy density per unit volume and energy density per unit mass is. If specifying a type of voltaic pile helps then I choose zamboni pile.

I had trouble finding numbers online. What I know is the voltage of a unit cell is ~.8, current in nanoampere range, the oxford bell has been on for more than 100 years. But I'm hesitant to use the oxford bell because it doesn't discharge a continuous current. I was able to calculate a five penny battery contains about 1 mWh but I feel like there are more efficient voltaic piles than it.

Comment: Kind of old technology to be curious about. I don't think using Wikipedia (yes, I literally saw verbatim where you retrieved this information) as a source to understand something. Textbooks would give you more conceptual understanding :)

Comment: @KingDuken Do you have any suggestions? I expected textbooks to detail more of the conceptual things but did not expect them to list figures of merit like energy density of commercial or historical voltaic piles.

Comment: Manganese oxide on silver with purified honey makes an excellent dielectric with very low leakage. But it attracts ants that can degrade it unless well sealed. Most silver oxide batteries have low leakage but degraded with rising temperature, which Is why all our payload silver cell batteries ( heavy duty) were kept in the fridge.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly estimate the maximum energy density of a pile if you understand the chemistry.

You know (or should) how many electrons you can get per atom from the anode, ditto to the cathode.  You know (or should) whether the electrolyte is consumed (like in a lead-acid cell) or acts like a catalyst.

Then for a given design you estimate the number of electrons you can get from the anode, the number of electrons you can put into the cathode, and the number of electrons that can pass through the electrolyte.  Whichever is minimum determines the total capacity of the cell.

Then, multiply that capacity in Coulombs by whatever you want to estimate for the cell voltage, and you get the stored energy in Joules.  Then divide that by mass or volume or whatever you want the energy density to be relative to.